# How is $\sum_{i=1}^{b}\frac{b}{b-i+1} = b \sum_{i=1}^{b}\frac{1}{i} $?

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory, algorithms

I am studying bins and balls experiment from Introduction to Algorithms by CLRS. We are finding the expected number of tosses for every bin to contain at least one ball. I do not understand this equation.

Comment: Set $$b-i+1=k$$

Comment: write down sum explicitly, turn around the summation order, write as indexed sum again

Answer (score 2):

You are simply reversing the summation: 
$$\begin{align}
& \sum_{i=1}^{b}\frac{b}{b-i+1} \\= &  b \sum_{i=1}^{b}\frac{1}{b-i+1} \\= & b \left( \frac1{b}+\frac1{b-1}+\cdots+\frac12+\frac11\right) \\
= & b \left( \frac1{1}+\frac1{2}+\cdots+\frac1{b-1}+\frac1b\right) \\
= & b \sum_{i=1}^{b}\frac{1}{i}
\end{align}$$